# Angular 2 AppLevel Service not injecting into child component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I will give a simplified example to explain my problem.

**app.module.ts**

```
...
providers: [MyService]
...
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template:'<child></child>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {} <-- my service has been injected successfully
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template:'<h1>child</h1>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {} <-- Error: No provider for MyService
}
```

I was under the impression that once a service provider is declared, that same service is available to that component and all it's child branches in it's tree.

I can fix the problem by adding the provider to the child:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template:'<h1>child</h1>',
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {} <-- Now it loads fine, but is it a new instance?
}
```

However this has left me confused on how DI works in angular.  Why I'm I getting Error: No provider for MyService?

**EDIT**

Found the problem, will leave it here incase it helps anyone.  It was not with Angular DI as my plunker example couldn't replicate the issue.  It turns out that the url part of

```
import { MyService } from './services/myService.service';
```

is case sensitive.  In the app module and parent model it was all lower case whilst in the child it as Camel Case.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker? And tell us about angular version

Comment: That's annoying no, I can't https://plnkr.co/edit/rvG5gs?p=preview Now I'm really stumped.  This is going to be a nightmare to isolate.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yIE6quSVG7T6Z35rLDCN?p=preview As  you can see all work pretty good. So hard to tell where you went wrong without example

Comment: Yeah, I get the error in my Production app but not in the example. It's going to be a right pain do find the cause.

Comment: @yurzui found the issue, thanks for your input.

Comment: I am glad to hear.